# Connection refused SQL - laravel, console command

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-artisan

I try to create console command `artisan`. I use this manual for it https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-artisan-commands-to-manage-database-records-in-laravel

But when I try `docker-compose exec app php artisan link:new`

I have `` SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: insert into `time_entries` (`id`, `comments`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, qqq, 2022-08-19 06:13:54, 2022-08-19 06:13:54)) ``

But my site works with this database without any mistakes.

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
ports:
  - 3307:3306
restart: unless-stopped
```

Why can I have this mistake?

Comment: Sometimes the mysql container needs  a little bit more time to completely boot up, just do docker-compose up and try again

Comment: @lewis4u I try this command ang now I have ```/usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections``` for ```mysql``` without continuation

Comment: Then I try to Ctrl+C to stop it. But now when I try ```docker-compose exec app php artisan link:new``` nothing happening

Comment: Shouldn't `DB_HOST=mysql` or whatever name you are using for your MySQL container?